# OWN CSS_JQueryMobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am using jquerymobile for developing app. I want to change the UI(button,list) colors,text and size based on my own css. Is it possible to do ? How Can I do it>

Please Advise me.

THanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the jquery mobile CSS and edit it or create a new CSS file and your own classes.

It's just CSS, nothing more.

Comment: I tried to create my own CSS. But it does not reflect in the button. Still it showing the default color. Please advise me.

Comment: 1. use firebug to fiddle with existing elements and their css. you probably refer to an element that is being hidden by jqm and replaced with other stuff. 2. look through jqm's css after you get the grip of what is happening to your page when jqm kicks in. 3. try to create a new theme or replace one of existing themes. they are called with single letters a to e